# for SVG, text-decoration:line-through not work when the postion 'y' is not an integer in IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/genaberuci/1/edit)

the line-through of two 'tspan' in demo can work correctly in Chrome, but fail in IE.

In IE, if you change the 'y' of the second 'tspan' to 45, you can see the line-through will work correctly as the first 'tspan'.

Moreover, if you increase the font-size to 15pt or more, the line-through will also work correctly.

Is this a bug in IE(can't draw line-through in some specific position)? or do I miss something important?

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: I faced this problem and it seems to be browser specific issue.